# ¿Cómo reemplazar valor 0 por números aleatorios o correlativos sin que se repitan?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Llevo poco tiempo aprendiendo a programar en Python y me encontré con el siguiente problema. Inicialmente cargo un archivo Excel con varias columnas, pero me interesa cambiar los valores que están en 0 en una columna específica que se llama 'SAP ORDEN' por valores únicos, ya sean correlativos o aleatorios.

He probado muchas formas y nada me resulta.

Este es el código:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('1.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Hoja1', header = 0)

df['SAP ORDEN'] = df['SAP ORDEN'].fillna(0)
df['SAP ORDEN'] = df['SAP ORDEN'].astype(int)
#print(df['SAP ORDEN'])

n = 0
for i in df['SAP ORDEN']:
    if i == 0:
        df['SAP ORDEN'] = n+1

print(df['SAP ORDEN'])
```

SAP ORDEN es un campo que viene en float y lo paso a int.

Esta es la lista inicial:

[image: Esta es la lista inicial]

Y el resultado que me da es este:

[image: Y el resultado que me da es este]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día,

**Nota:** Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable no utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el `dataset` rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un `for` entonces es el camino incorrecto (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces `apply` podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos.

La forma más fácil de realizar lo que deseas es crear una serie que detecte los valores que son `NaN` y cree una suma acumulada de esas "celdas". Luego utilizamos `fillna` con esa serie y listo, asigna a cada `NaN` un valor incremental.

Ejemplo utilizando un `dataframe` genérico:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'SAP ORDEN': [123,456,np.nan,789,np.nan,np.nan]})

# Creamos una serie de los elementos que son NaN
# y al ser la suma acumulada se irá incrementando
s = (df['SAP ORDEN'].isna().cumsum()).astype(int)

# Utilizamos fillna con la serie creada anteriormente
df['SAP ORDEN'].fillna(s, inplace=True)
df['SAP ORDEN'] = df['SAP ORDEN'].astype(int)
print(df)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
   SAP ORDEN
0        123
1        456
2          1
3        789
4          2
5          3
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto y muchas gracias por la recomendación!

Answer (score 2):

```
n = 0
for i in range( len( df[ 'SAP ORDEN' ] )):
    print( df[ 'SAP ORDEN' ][i] )
    if df[ 'SAP ORDEN' ][i] == 0:
        df[ 'SAP ORDEN' ][i] = n+1
        n += 1   
   
print( df[ 'SAP ORDEN' ])
```

Solo te faltaba actualizar el valor de `n`.
Si bien corregí la función para que hiciera lo que se pide, la explicación de Heytale, deja claro que no es el mejor camino.

Comment: Al añadir el n+=1 me da un resultado similar al anterior, me reemplaza todo por el total del contador, pero con la respuesta de Heytale funcionó 10/10.
Gracias igual!

Comment: @Jorge, Corregido Maestro, pero ya quedó claro que la respuesta de Heytale, es la mejor!!.